# Menu and content dissapears after JUpdate Joomla 1.5-2.5

Tags: php, templates, joomla, localhost

With some struggle i setup an test area and updated the joomla template of an customer.
I used JUpdate for this.

The template is custom and i rebuild it from 1.5 for the use in 2.5.

The original site http://imgdump.nl/hosted/7a5613219515d86549301252eca2837e.png

The site in the updated joomla http://imgdump.nl/hosted/ef214bab43ee5508798d84cee7d2d6fb.png

Does anyone know what couses this to happen ? is it in updating the template or is it anything else?

Also tried if the menu structure is still working and as far as i can see its still all linked.

If its a great possibility its becourse of the template code i will post it later.

I dont got an PARAM section in the 1.5 template could this mess it up if i try to convert it to 2.5 ? (i got an POSITION section with the sections of the site)

```
<files>
    <filename>index.php</filename>
    <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
    <filename>template_thumbnail.png</filename>
    <filename>templates.php</filename>
    <filename>template_preview.png</filename>
    <filename>error.php</filename>

    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>images</folder>

</files>
<positions>
    <position>user4</position>            
    <position>user3</position>            
    <position>breadcrumb</position>            
    <position>user2</position>            
    <position>left</position>                  
    <position>right</position>            
    <position>debug</position>       
</positions>
```

---

```
<body id="page_bg">
    <div id="container">
        <?php if($this->countModules('user4') and JRequest::getCmd('layout') != 'form') : ?>
        <div id="search_bg">
            <div id="search">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" />    
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div id="nosearch"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="pillmenu">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" />
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumb" />
            <div id="outside"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="header">
            <div id="headerimg"></div>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1><a href="index.php"><!-- <?php echo $mainframe->getCfg('sitename') ;?><!--test--></a></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="boxes">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" style="rounded" name="user2" />
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="content_top">
                <div id="content_bottom">
                    <?php if($this->countModules('left') and JRequest::getCmd('layout') != 'form') : ?>
                    <div id="leftcolumn">   
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="rounded" />
<br /><?php $sg = "banner"; include "templates.php"; ?><br />

                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if($this->countModules('right') and JRequest::getCmd('layout') != 'form') : ?>            
                    <div id="maincolumn">
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <div id="maincolumn_full">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="nopad">             
                            <jdoc:include type="message" />
                            <?php if($this->params->get('showComponent')) : ?>
                                <jdoc:include type="component" />
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if($this->countModules('right') and JRequest::getCmd('layout') != 'form') : ?>
                    <div id="rightcolumn" style="float:right;">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="rounded" />                                
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'd check that the modules are still assigned to the right positions.

Comment: i assume they are ? when i tried an standard 2.5 template its all in the right place

Comment: tested nothing changes

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Based on the image and how the template ends abruptly there may be a php error that is causing it to stop executing.

Comment: ya i think error reporting is on ? but dont got alot of knowledge abouth this haha